# Pandas Dataframe Count Categorical data by row, group by datetime index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a timeseries Dataframe of Categorical values.

I'd like to count unique categorical values into new columns (named by value), like so:

```
df           a     b     c                df1         x     y
17/6/2021    x     x     y                17/6/2021   2     1
18/6/2021    x     x     x   >>>>>>>>>    18/6/2021   3     0
19/6/2021    y     x     x                19/6/2021   2     1
20/6/2021    y     y     y                20/6/2021   0     3
```

Would appreciate any guidance on what function is suitable for this task. TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
df = df.set_index('<your date column name>').apply(pd.Series.value_counts, 1).fillna(0)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '17/6/2021', 1: '18/6/2021', 2: '19/6/2021', 3: '20/6/2021'},
              'a': {0: 'x', 1: 'x', 2: 'y', 3: 'y'},
              'b': {0: 'x', 1: 'x', 2: 'x', 3: 'y'},
              'c': {0: 'y', 1: 'x', 2: 'x', 3: 'y'}})

df1 = df.set_index('date').apply(pd.Series.value_counts, 1).fillna(0)
df1
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
             x    y
date               
17/6/2021  2.0  1.0
18/6/2021  3.0  0.0
19/6/2021  2.0  1.0
20/6/2021  0.0  3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) + [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
s = df.melt('date')
df1 = pd.crosstab(s['date'], s['value']).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

```
        date  x  y
0  17/6/2021  2  1
1  18/6/2021  3  0
2  19/6/2021  2  1
3  20/6/2021  0  3
```

Benefit of this approach is the counts are of the correct type (`int`) since NaNs are not introduced converting the `dtype` to `float`.

---

Explaination:

`melt` converts data to long form:

```
s = df.melt('date')
```

```
         date variable value
0   17/6/2021        a     x
1   18/6/2021        a     x
2   19/6/2021        a     y
3   20/6/2021        a     y
4   17/6/2021        b     x
5   18/6/2021        b     x
6   19/6/2021        b     x
7   20/6/2021        b     y
8   17/6/2021        c     y
9   18/6/2021        c     x
10  19/6/2021        c     x
11  20/6/2021        c     y
```

Then `crosstab` between `date` and `value`:

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(s['date'], s['value'])
```

```
value      x  y
date           
17/6/2021  2  1
18/6/2021  3  0
19/6/2021  2  1
20/6/2021  0  3
```

Lastly cleanup axis names and index:

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(s['date'], s['value']).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

```
        date  x  y
0  17/6/2021  2  1
1  18/6/2021  3  0
2  19/6/2021  2  1
3  20/6/2021  0  3
```